# Variation of conductance of saturated aqueous solution with temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry, electrochemistry, aqueous-solution, solutions

The following question was asked in JEE Mains 2020:

> Let $C_{\ce{NaCl}}$ and $C_{\ce{BaSO4}}$ be the conductances (in S) measured for saturated aqueous solutions of $\ce{NaCl}$ and $\ce{BaSO4}$, respectively, at a temperature $T$. Which of the following is **false**?
>
> (A) Ionic mobilities of ions from both salts increase with $T$ 
> (B) $C_{\ce{NaCl}} >> C_{\ce{BaSO4}}$ at a given $T$ 
> (C) $C_{\ce{NaCl}}$($T_2$) > $C_{\ce{NaCl}}$($T_1$) for $T_2 > T_1$ 
> (D) $C_{\ce{BaSO4}}$($T_2$) > $C_{\ce{BaSO4}}$($T_1$) for $T_2 > T_1$

My attempt:

(A) As temperature increases viscosity decreases leading to higher mobility, hence this is true.

(B) $\ce{BaSO4}$ is almost insoluble in water, hence its saturated solution will have a much smaller quantity of ions compared to an $\ce{NaCl}$ saturated solution, hence this is true.

(C) [As can be seen from the graph here](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/69047/24750), the solublity of $\ce{NaCl}$ does increase with temperature, but only slightly; nevertheless this option is also true because it does increase and also ionic mobility increases.

(D) Dissolution of $\ce{BaSO4}$ is an endothermic process, hence I would expect solubility (hence conductance) to increase with temperature (although I was not able to find any data), therefore this option is also true.

Where am I going wrong? This is a single-correct question. The given answer is:

> (A), but there are varied options found all over the web for this question

Comment: The answers are self-contradictory. If C and D are correct, then A *must* be correct. It cannot be false. Ion mobilities increase with temperature in solutions. I don't know what the examiner was thinking when writing this question.

Comment: Barium sulfate solubility increases with temperature. Here values from Kohlrausch : $\pu{3°C - 0.207 mg/L ; 18°C - 0.23 mg/L ; 26°C - 0.266 mg/L ; 34°C - 0.29 mg/L}$ These values are cited in a recent report : Arbaoui M. Ali, Energy Procedia 157 (2019) 879 - 891.

Comment: There can be catch if they mean NaCl solution is saturated at all T ( with excess of solid salt) or if just saturated solution is taken and heated up, becoming unsaturated. For the former, there can be competition of mobility increase due T versus effective mobility decrease for big electrolyte concentrations ( due ion atmosphere and ionic pair formation) .

Comment: But as NaCl solubility does not change much, I guess positive T effect on ion mobility would dominate.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, there is actually a trick way to solve the question. If any of A, C or D are false the one of the others also becomes false. (As mentioned by @AChem).
So the only option left is (B), which should (ideally) be the correct answer.

Now, coming to the actual reason, as per what I’ve found, conductivity ($k$) of salts in $aqueous$ solution depends on their concentration and number of ions generated on dissociation.

$k$ in aqueous solution or water : $Ba^{2+}$ > $Na^+$.
$k$ in molten state : $Ba^{2+}$ > $Na^+$.

Comment: Please don't use MathJax for emphasis. Note that [chemical element symbols are upright](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443). Taglines such as "*Hope it helps*" are unnecessary noise. There are several IUPAC standard symbols for different conductivities, but none of them include $k$ (you can look them up in [IUPAC Green Book](https://iupac.org/what-we-do/books/greenbook/)). It would probably make sense to back up your answer by an equation or some literature data.

Comment: @andselisk Ah thanks again ! Actually I have trouble typing super scripts so use mathjax, also could you please tell me how I can italicise text ?

Comment: @andselisk also, “ The thermal conductivity of a material is a measure of its ability to conduct heat. It is commonly denoted by k, k, λ “, from Wikipedia. k(kappa) is used for conductivity. I don’t have any equation or data as such for the question, only reasoning from various sites I extracted.

Comment: One can use `$\kappa$` to get $\kappa$. // Useful links for text and formula formatting:
 [Notation basics](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation)  /  [Formatting of math/chem expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here)  /  
[upright vs italic](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/443/which-symbols-are-written-in-roman-upright-font-and-which-are-italicized) // Use plain texts in CH SE titles.

Comment: You are welcome. //  For more, see [Math SE MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).